# Square orders create via API on website don't show on dashboard

Tags: php, api, orders, square

I'm currently using square/connect-php-sdk createOrder to create a Square Order.

```
$api_config = new SquareConnect\Configuration();
$api_config->setAccessToken($access_token);
$api_config->setHost($host);
$api_client = new SquareConnect\ApiClient($api_config);
$apiInstance = new SquareConnect\Api\OrdersApi($api_client);
$orderRequest = new SquareConnect\Model\CreateOrderRequest();
$orderRequest->setIdempotencyKey(uniqid());
$order = new SquareConnect\Model\Order();
$money = new SquareConnect\Model\Money();
$money->setAmount(intval(500))
    ->setCurrency("USD");
$line_item = new SquareConnect\Model\OrderLineItem();
$line_item->setCatalogObjectId(<square item id>)
    ->setQuantity("1")
    ->setBasePriceMoney($money);
$line_items[] = $line_item;
$order->setLineItems($line_items);
$orderRequest->setOrder($order);
$result = $apiInstance->createOrder($location_id, $orderRequest);
```

This returns an Order ID (along with other order data) which I store locally.
I then process a credit card using the Square Payment Form: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payment-form/payment-form-walkthrough

This gives me a nonce which I then send with the Order ID and the price.

```
$apiInstance = new SquareConnect\Api\PaymentsApi($api_client);
$paymentRequest = new SquareConnect\Model\CreatePaymentRequest();
$paymentRequest->setIdempotencyKey(uniqid());
$paymentRequest->setLocationId($location_id);
$money = new SquareConnect\Model\Money();
$money->setAmount(intval($total_cost))
    ->setCurrency("USD");
$paymentRequest->setAmountMoney($money);
$paymentRequest->setOrderId($sq_order_id);
$paymentRequest->setSourceId($nonce);
$result = $apiInstance->createPayment($paymentRequest);
```

This gives me a Payment ID (along with other payment data).
On the Square Dashboard, I am able to see the transaction in the Transactions section, but the Orders section of the dashboard is empty.

My question is How do I get it to show in the Orders section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the order to show up in your dashboard you need to do two things:
1. Pay for the order (it sounds like you did this part)
2. Include a `fulfillments` parameter in the `CreateOrder` request: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/orders-api/order-ahead-usecase#add-fulfillment-information-to-make-a-pickup-order