# Using Square API, how do I get my orders to appear in the Sandbox Dashboard?

Tags: php, api, sandbox, dashboard, square

The following code seems to work in producing an order. In the API explorer, I can Batch Retrieve Order by that order ID and I get the right response but It doesn't show up in my Sandbox dashboard. I'm definitely using my sandbox credentials and my env has PROD set to false.

How do I get orders to appear in my Sandbox (and eventually the production) Dashboard?

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

# dotenv is used to read from the '.env' file created for credentials
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();


# The access token to use in all Connect API requests. Use your *sandbox* access
# token if you're just testing things out.
$access_token = ($_ENV["USE_PROD"] == 'true')  ?  $_ENV["PROD_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
                                               :  $_ENV["SANDBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN"];

$location_id = ($_ENV["USE_PROD"] == 'true')  ?  $_ENV["PROD_LOCATION_ID"]
                                               :  $_ENV["SANDBOX_LOCATION_ID"];     

# Set 'Host' url to switch between sandbox env and production env
# sandbox: https://connect.squareupsandbox.com
# production: https://connect.squareup.com
$host_url = ($_ENV["USE_PROD"] == 'true')  ?  "https://connect.squareup.com"
                                           :  "https://connect.squareupsandbox.com";

$api_config = new \SquareConnect\Configuration();
$api_config->setHost($host_url);

# Initialize the authorization for Square
$api_config->setAccessToken($access_token);
$api_client = new \SquareConnect\ApiClient($api_config);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
  error_log("Received a non-POST request");
  echo "Request not allowed";
  http_response_code(405);
  return;
}

$order_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\OrdersApi($api_client);

$price = new \SquareConnect\Model\Money;
$price->setAmount(600);
$price->setCurrency('USD');

$item = new \SquareConnect\Model\OrderLineItem;
$item->setName('Item');
$item->setQuantity('2');
$item->setBasePriceMoney($price);

$customer = new \SquareConnect\Model\OrderFulfillmentRecipient;
$customer->setDisplayName('John');

$pickup_details = new \SquareConnect\Model\OrderFulfillmentPickupDetails;
$pickup_details->setRecipient($customer);
$pickup_details->setPickupAt('2020-01-26T02:25:34Z');

$pickup = new \SquareConnect\Model\OrderFulfillment;
$pickup->setUid(uniqid());
$pickup->setState('PROPOSED');
$pickup->setType('PICKUP');
$pickup->setPickupDetails($pickup_details);

$lineItems = array();
array_push($lineItems, $item);

$fullfillment = array();
array_push($fullfillment, $pickup);

$order = new \SquareConnect\Model\Order;
$order->setLineItems($lineItems);
$order->setFulfillments($fullfillment);

$request = new \SquareConnect\Model\CreateOrderRequest();
$request->setIdempotencyKey(uniqid()); //uniqid() generates a random string.
$request->setOrder($order);

try {
    $result = $order_api->createOrder($location_id, $request);
    print_r($result);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Exception when calling OrdersApi->createOrder:', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Using the Order ID created from that POST I receive the following response in Square's API explorer.
The order info and fulfillment details are correct. It doesn't appear in the Sandbox dashboard. What am I missing to make this happen?

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "id": "--Unique Order ID--",
      "location_id": "--My Location ID--",
      "line_items": [
        {
          "uid": "--Unique Item id--",
          "quantity": "2",
          "name": "Item",
          "base_price_money": {
            "amount": 600,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "gross_sales_money": {
            "amount": 1200,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_tax_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_discount_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "total_money": {
            "amount": 1200,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "variation_total_price_money": {
            "amount": 1200,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        }
      ],
      "fulfillments": [
        {
          "uid": "--Unique fulfillment ID--",
          "type": "PICKUP",
          "state": "PROPOSED",
          "pickup_details": {
            "pickup_at": "2020-01-26T02:25:34.000Z",
            "recipient": {
              "display_name": "John"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "created_at": "2020-05-20T21:55:46.677Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-05-20T21:55:46.677Z",
      "state": "OPEN",
      "version": 1,
      "total_tax_money": {
        "amount": 0,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "total_discount_money": {
        "amount": 0,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "total_tip_money": {
        "amount": 0,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "total_money": {
        "amount": 1200,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "total_service_charge_money": {
        "amount": 0,
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "net_amounts": {
        "total_money": {
          "amount": 1200,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "tax_money": {
          "amount": 0,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "discount_money": {
          "amount": 0,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "tip_money": {
          "amount": 0,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "service_charge_money": {
          "amount": 0,
          "currency": "USD"
        }
      },
      "source": {
        "name": "Sandbox for --My Sandbox Id-- "
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I create this order request without any payment request. I was testing the order first. I don't think the absence of payment would prohibit the order from registering but I'm new to the Square API.

Comment: Take a look here and let me know if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60480685/square-orders-create-via-api-on-website-dont-show-on-dashboard